# Views: count and filter by entity field value

Tags: views

I have many nodes of type 'Players' and 'Match'. In the 'Match' node there is an entity field 'Strikers' referenced to 'Players' which allow multiple values.

I'd like to create a player page that shows information about that player searching all occurrence of that player in the 'Match' nodes (inside the 'strikers' field of each node).

I tried with the contextual filter but I don't know if it is the correct way..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going of memory here, this might be wrong:

Add contextual filter of node id (nid) (so the player nid goes here)

Add a RELANTIONSHIP of Strikers Referencing Entity and checkmark the box that says, "force relantionship" or something along those lines.

Comment: I created a view with a path like 'player/%/info' and I add the contextual filter of node id (I use alias path, I hope it's not a problem). Then I create the relationship 'Content referencing Content from field_strikers'.

Unfortunately I don't see any result in the preview..

Comment: @AndreaMoraglia **since your contextual filter is in the url, your view preview won't show any results**. You need to go to, for example:  `/player/5/info` to see if it works. OR temporarily change your contextual filter to **fixed** then enter 5  or a player nid there and then your preview will work.

Comment: Thanks! I solved selecting "Content ID from URL" inside the contextual filter and using a relationship 'Content referencing Content from field_strikers'. Then I turned on the aggregation and the rows number in the result is the information I needed.

Getting the Content ID from URL solved the problem of pahauto alias. I also insert the view as field inside player so when I see player profile I get the view at the bottom of the page. Thank You!

Comment: It's possible to filter the content ID on many field? I'd like to do the same query on more field ('strikers', 'substituted', 'cautioned' ecc..) then count the number of occurences

Comment: @AndreaMoraglia You would have to create a different view block for each.  There is no way to count all of them at the same time.

Comment: @AndreaMoraglia an alternative could be adding integer fields to your Players content type. Ex: Strikers count Substituted Count and Cautioned Count. Then using Rules module you can +1 the field every time a new Match node is added and references the player.